# What is the missing operator in this VBA Code?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I built this code as a test to delete a range of records from an Access 2013 database based upon a range of dates.  I'm getting a missing operator error in query expression 'START_DATE >= .....etc.   I have tried the select statement with apostrophes as well.

NOTE: the CALL line is all one line in the actual code.  Also, if I run the CALL line with Between/AND instead of >= / <= , the code completes with no errors, but does not accomplish anything.  It does not find and delete the rows.

```
  Function Delete_Range()

  Dim begdt As Date
  Dim enddt As Date

 'user inputs date range
  begdt = InputBox("Enter beginning date as mm/01/yyyy", "BEGINNING DATE")
  enddt = InputBox("Enter ending date as mm/01/yyyy", "ENDING DATE")


  Dim objectrecordset As ADODB.Recordset
  Set objectrecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

 'initiate recordset object
 objectrecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
 Call objectrecordset.Open("select START_DATE 
 from TEMP_DATE_RANGE where START_DATE IS >= "
 & begdt & " AND <= " & enddt, , , adLockBatchOptimistic)

 While objectrecordset.EOF = False
 'delete record
 objectrecordset.Delete
 objectrecordset.UpdateBatch

 'move to next record
 objectrecordset.MoveNext
 Wend

 End Function
```

Thank you everybody for your help.  Here is the code that worked.

```
 DoCmd.SetWarnings (warningsoff)

 'Declare variables
 Dim begdt As String
 Dim enddt As String

 'User inputs variables
 begdt = InputBox("Enter beginning date as mm/01/yyyy", "BEGINNING DATE")
 enddt = InputBox("Enter ending date as mm/01/yyyy", "ENDING DATE")

 'Format variable as date and error handling
 If Not (IsDate(begdt) And IsDate(enddt)) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a date using a the date format", vbOKOnly
     GoTo Finished

 Else
    begdt = Format(begdt, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
    enddt = Format(enddt, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")

 End If

 'Delete records from tables based upon user input date range
 Dim SQL As String
 Dim SQL2 As String
 Dim SQL3 As String

  SQL = "DELETE * FROM TEST_TBL_1 WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN " & begdt & " AND " & enddt & ""
 SQL2 = "DELETE * FROM TEST_TBL_2 WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN " & begdt & " AND " & enddt & ""
 SQL3 = "DELETE * FROM TEST_TBL_3 WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN " & begdt & " AND " & enddt & ""

 DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
 DoCmd.RunSQL SQL2
 DoCmd.RunSQL SQL3

 'Close form and show process complete page
 DoCmd.SetWarnings (warningson)
 DoCmd.Close acForm, "DELETE HISTORY", acSaveNo
 DoCmd.OpenForm "COMPLETE", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal

 Finished:

 End Function
```

Comment: would it not be simpler to use something like the following `db.execute ("DELETE * FROM TEMP_DATE_RANGE WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN #" & begdt & "# AND #" & enddt & "#")` or am I missing something here? why do you need to select and call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up date values and string expressions for these, and it all starts with your inputbox which always returns a string:

```
Dim begdt As String
Dim enddt As String

' user inputs date range
begdt = InputBox("Enter beginning date as mm/01/yyyy", "BEGINNING DATE")
enddt = InputBox("Enter ending date as mm/01/yyyy", "ENDING DATE")

If Not (IsDate(begdt) And IsDate(enddt)) Then
    ' Show error.
Else
    begdt = Format(begdt, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#)
    enddt = Format(enddt, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#)

    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "Select START_DATE From TEMP_DATE_RANGE Where START_DATE Between " & begdt & " And " & enddt & ""
    Dim objectrecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set objectrecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

   'initiate recordset object
   objectrecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
   Call objectrecordset.Open(SQL, , , adLockBatchOptimistic)

   ' <Snip>
   ' Clean up.
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

First work out the query logic and syntax in the Access query designer.  Assuming *START_DATE* is Date/Time datatype, pick a couple static values for the start and end of your target date range:

```sql
SELECT START_DATE 
FROM TEMP_DATE_RANGE
WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN #2015-1-1# AND #2015-10-30#
```

Adjust as needed.

Once you have the proper SQL statement, build the corresponding statement text in your VBA code.

```vb
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "SELECT START_DATE FROM TEMP_DATE_RANGE " & _
    "WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN " & Format(begdt,"\#yyyy-m-d\#") & _
    " AND " & Format(enddt,"\#yyyy-m-d\#")
Debug.Print strSelect '<- inspect this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
```

Then you can use *strSelect* with `objectrecordset.Open`

However, since your goal is to delete those rows, you don't actually need a recordset.  You can simply execute a `DELETE` statement instead.

```sql
DELETE FROM TEMP_DATE_RANGE
WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN #2015-1-1# AND #2015-10-30#
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you don't write:

```
where a < 8 and > 7
```

You write:

```
where a < 8 and a > 7
```

So, you need to fix the `where` clause:

```
objectrecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
 Call objectrecordset.Open("select START_DATE 
 from TEMP_DATE_RANGE where START_DATE IS >= "
 & begdt & " AND START_DATE <= " & enddt, , , adLockBatchOptimistic)
-----------------^
```

There may be other problems, but this is an obvious one in the SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to insert some single quotes around your dates in the query string.  Like this:

```
Call objectrecordset.Open("select START_DATE from TEMP_DATE_RANGE where START_DATE BETWEEN '"  & begdt & "' AND '" & enddt & "'", , , adLockBatchOptimistic)
```

**** I edited this to replace the is >= with a between statement too

Answer (score -1):

Your date comparison syntax is a little off, remove `IS` in `IS >=` and remember to add `START_DATE <=` rather than just `<=`

With the corrections, it becomes:

```
Call objectrecordset.Open("select START_DATE 
 from TEMP_DATE_RANGE where START_DATE >= "
& begdt & " AND START_DATE <= " & enddt, , , adLockBatchOptimistic)
```